# How to copy a reference to a File object in Java

Tags: java, file, file-io, java-8, java-7

```
File file = new File ("image.gif");

// Is this a copy, a reference, or something else?
File File2 = file;
```

What I'm trying to do is copy a reference to a File object. I don't want to make a duplicate and I'm not sure if the above code is copying a reference or copying the object. I'm trying to avoid memory leaks or orphans, especially if I were to delete the file from within the code.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you think a `File` object is or represents? Why do you think so?

Comment: An object that is a reference to a file on disk? File is the class which facilitates this.

Comment: It is not a reference to a file on disk. It is a java class, that stores the path to real file on the disk, and provides you with methods to manipulate that file, but it does not reference it for sure.

Comment: In 2015 you shouldn't be looking at `File` but [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) instead

Comment: @fge You're right. But for Java 6, I don't believe `Path` works. I still work with Java 5 and 6 sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object is

> An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.

It's just a fancy `String` (with methods that do interact with file systems).

`file` is a variable. A variable holds values. Since this is a reference type variable, it holds reference values.

`new File ("image.gif");` is an expression that creates a new object and produces a reference value (referencing the newly created object).

`File2` is another variable. When you perform the assignment

```
File File2 = file;
```

the value stored in `file` is copied and the copy is stored in `File2`.

This is the same concept as binding argument values to method parameters, discussed in:

- [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: This is really, really great stuff. Thank you very much. I'll be sure to take a look at that pass-by-reference or pass-by-value stackoverflow link.

Comment: @user3621633 I also recommend [Pass-by-Value Please (Cup Size continued)](http://www.javaranch.com/campfire/StoryPassBy.jsp) (and its first part - [Cup Size -- a story about variables](http://www.javaranch.com/campfire/StoryCups.jsp))

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you. I'll take a look at those links. I read through that original link in the answer. It's similar to C or C++, the pass-by-value vs pass-by-reference, right? In Java, you (almost?) never  point to a pointer (reference). You're pointing to a value and there could be multiple pointers pointing to the same value.

Answer (score 3):

What you just did is: you created another variable `File2` that points to the exactly same object on the *heap*. **A new object is not created!**

If you would manipulate any of the variables, you would manipulate the same object on the *heap*. A new one is not created in the process. A new object is created only with the `new` keyword (or with some Reflection, but that's out of the scope now).

---

Also, make sure to read about where are variables created, where do objects reside during program's runtime and what are *heap* and *stack* (search for: "java heap vs stack").

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your wisdom. I will definitely search for that term.

Answer (score 1):

To copy a file object:

```
File f = new File("home/users", "alice/documents");
File copied = new File(f.getPath());

System.out.println(copied.equals(f)); // true
System.out.println(copied == f);      // false
```

Usually, this is not necessary. But one case it may be useful is when you want a constructor from File when you subclass java.io.File:

```
public class MyFile extends File {
    public MyFile(File path) {
        super(path.getPath());
    }

    // ...
```